# grep expression behaving weird (unix/mac) while reading a conf file

Tags: regex, shell, unix, scripting, grep

What's going wrong in below grep expression, appreciate any help.

$cat foo.txt

```
## not to be read
; this one too and next one also coz it has sapce
first_var= first_val
second_var=y
second_var=yes
```

Now when I run below grep on Mac/Linux

```
 grep "^[^#;].*[^[:space:]]\=[^[:space:]].*[^=]" foo.txt
```

I get below output

```
second_var=yes
```

whereas I was expecting

```
second_var=y
second_var=yes
```

what I am going wrong here?

Comment: You can probably use `grep -E "^[^#;](.*[^[:space:]])?=[^[:space:]](.*[^=])?" foo.txt`

Answer (score 3):

In the part after the `=` you expect 2 characters, and you only have a single `y`

You could make the second part optional if it should end on any character except `=`

```
grep "^[^#;].*[^[:space:]]=[^[:space:]]\(.*[^=]\)\?" foo.txt
```

Output

```
second_var=y
second_var=yes
```

Comment: Understood, it was a two characters test when we do [^[:space:]] and a dot after it. Thanks for quick help.

Comment: Good catch for single character RHS

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "^[^#;].*[^[:space:]]\=[^[:space:]][^=]*" foo.txt
```

works as it specifies that `=` must be followed by a sequence of chars excepted `=`:

```
second_var=y
second_var=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided `grep` solutions solve your problem though I suggest considering this `awk` solution for the sake of the simplicity and readability:

```bash
awk -F= 'NF==2 && !/^;|[[:space:]]=|=[[:space:]]/' file

second_var=y
second_var=yes
```